# Android load data from Sqlite to CalendarView

Tags: android, sqlite

I have been trying to load some data to a calendar.My main goal is to load some data from the Database and to display it in the calendar when was that specific thing done.I have not been able to find anything specific about calendars,and how can i do this.Can someone guide me a bit in the right direction about calendars.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the CalendarProvider:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html

This way you can edit/add/remove events into the native Calendar application database on your device if this is want you intended to do.